# conditional where clause mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to find in my MySQL table a specific time-period.

I want to find the period that
1. started in the past (`cursusperiode_van < now()`)
2. and will last for at least 4 weeks (`cursusperiode_tot - INTERVAL 28 DAY > now()`)
3. If i don't find this one, i would like to find the one that is the first to start after this one (`cursusperiode_van > now() order by cursusperiode_van asc limit 1`).

Periods do not overlap, at least not for more than 1 day.

Let's say i have

```
id:1 - period: 1 jan 2011 to 1 aug 2011
id:2 - period: 1 aug 2011 to 31 dec 2011
```

If i query that database on July 1, i want to find `id 1`, if i query on July 23, i want to find `id 2`.

Not likely to be relevant, but this query is to be embedded in another query like

```
select * from cursus where cursus_periode_id in (
    select cursusperiode_id from cursusperiode_id where ...[panic!] ...
) and so on
```

I tried to use IFNULL, CASE, but i can't seem to get my head around it. How do i paste these two together?
Any hint or help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could `UNION` both queries, add a dummy column to aid in sorting and retain the first one found.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  c1.* 
FROM    cursus c1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  1 AS Dummy
                    , cursusperiode_id 
            FROM    cursusperiode_id 
            WHERE   cursusperiode_tot - INTERVAL 28 DAY > now()
            UNION ALL    
            SELECT  2 AS Dummy
                    , cursusperiode_id 
            FROM    cursusperiode_id 
            WHERE   cursusperiode_van > now()    
        ) c2 ON c2.cursusperiod_id = c1.cursusperiod_id
ORDER BY
        c2.Dummy
        , c1.cursusperiode_van ASC
LIMIT   1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answe. The thingis, the query I need will function as a subquery in an existing query. Actually, a subquery using IN (`select * from table where id_field IN(subquery)`) and your solution has 2 columns as output, so it can't do the trick. I tried using your `UNION ALL` in another way, but i still can't get it right, because i need the Dummy column you also used to sort the outcome.

Comment: On a sidenote, the MySQL-version on my server cannot use ALL/IN together with LIMIT, so i added `select * from (` before the subquery and `)alias` just after it.

Comment: Instead of using `IN`, you could `JOIN` the results of this query with your table.

Comment: Lieven, i think i can't, because the query i use is generic and used in other places as well. I can always append `and id in (.. subquery ..)` but not a join. Using `IN` is paramount.